# Access instance variable from method

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I can't access the instance variable from method within the same class.

```
class GetImagesFromSinglePage(object):
     def __init__(self,source):
        self.source = source
        self.imgLinks = []
     def retrieveImg(source):
        #.....tasks
        self.imgLinks = tempimgLinks #there it show can't access that          variable
     def getLink(self):
        return self.imgLinks
```

What should I do?
Regards,
John

Comment: try `def retrieveImg(self, source):`

Comment: Where is `tempimgLinks` coming from?

Comment: hi, tempingLinks is variable within retrivingImg method(it already have value)

Comment: Yay, I got it, as Roberto said. I forgot to add "self" in retriveveImage methd as parameter. Thank Roberto. And also to jDo and Sam F